# Blazor Server - DbContext is disposed after refreshing page

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am developing a Blazor server app, where all clients will have a list of `things`, any one of these clients can update `thing` which should then trigger a callback telling all clients to call `DbContext.Entry(thing).Reload()` so they're up to date. This works all great and well until I refresh the page, then I get the `Cannot access a disposed object` error and I can't figure out how to get around it.

I have the follow services:

```cs
services.AddDbContextPool<MainDbContext>(...);
services.AddSingleton<RefreshService>();
```

RefreshService.cs:

```
public class RefreshService {
    public Func<long, Task> OnRefreshThing { get; set; }

    public void RefreshThing(long thingId) => OnRefreshThing?.Invoke(thingId);
}
```

Index.blazor:

```
protected override void OnInitialized() {
    RefreshService.OnRefreshIssue += OnRefreshIssue;
}
private async Task OnRefreshThing(long thingId) {
    // This works perfectly until I refresh the page & try to call it again
    Thing thing = await MainDbContext.Things.FindAsync(thingId); // exception is thrown here

    await MainDbContext.Entry(thing).ReloadAsync();
}
```

And here's an example of what triggers the error:

```
Thing thing = Things.Where(t => t.ThingId == 1);
thing.Name = "New name";
RefreshService.RefreshThing(thing.ThingId);
```

Comment: Web applications should be stateless. You are trying to use a singleton server side for a web app where state can be preserved which is not a good design decision. A DbContext instance should be either tied to the Request coming in or shorter lived like tied to the life of another instance that has scope inside the request. Do not use singletons to do anything with application state unless that state is static (like access to web.config settings).

Comment: Thanks. I went with your advice and got everything working!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can modify the RefreshService to be Scoped not Singleton
2. The AddDbContextPool does not dispose the instance of the dbcontext completely, it resets the instance to its default state and it could be because of the reset that it can't access it again